# Eventbrite API unable to create event using nodejs, getting error 403 not_authorized response

Tags: node.js, api, eventbrite

I am trying to create an Eventbrite event using API, here is my code

```
var request = require('request');
var EVENTBRITE_API_URL = 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/';
var _token = '<TOKEN>';

var _event = {
    "event.name.html": "TestEvent01",
    "event.description.html": "TestEvent01",
    "event.start.timezone": "America/Chicago",
    "event.start.utc": "2018-02-10T18:00:00Z",
    "event.end.timezone": "America/Chicago",
    "event.end.utc": "2018-02-10T20:00:00Z",
    "event.currency": "USD",
};

var request = require('request');
var _headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + _token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

// Configure the request
var options = {
    url: EVENTBRITE_API_URL + "events/",
    method: 'POST',
    headers: _headers,
    form: _event,
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error) {
    console.log(body);
  }
});
```

It's not working and I am getting the following response:

```
{"status_code": 403, "error_description": "You do not have permission to access the resource you requested.", "error": "NOT_AUTHORIZED"}
```

Can someone please shed a light what is wrong here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a node expert, but this looks okay to me. I'm guessing that you're not passing in the right token. You can create a token [here](https://www.eventbrite.com/myaccount/apps/). The token string you should pass in your authorization header is labeled **Your personal OAuth token**.

Cheers!

Comment: yes Chris! You were absolutely correct! I was passing just the key, not the oauth token, such a silly mistake of mine  :-)